# Extract keys from a list of dicts with single key-value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list which is like this:

```
[{0: 26},
 {0: 36},
 {1: 1},
 {0: 215},
 {1: 63},
 {0: 215}]
```

How can I extract a list of keys from it?

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dict.keys()` to get keys out of a dictionary and use it in a list-comprehension like below:

```
lst = [{0: 26},
       {0: 36},
       {1: 1},
       {0: 215},
       {1: 63},
       {0: 215}]

print([y for x in lst for y in x.keys()])
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Or, this should be further simplified as:

```
print([y for x in lst for y in x])
```

Because, when you simply iterate through dictionary like `for y in x`, you are actually iterating through keys of the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Use `dict.keys` to extract the keys of each of the dict, convert to a list, and then extract the first element

```
>>> lst = [{0: 26}, {0: 36}, {1: 1}, {0: 215}, {1: 63}, {0: 215}]
>>> [list(d.keys())[0] for d in lst]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Alternatively, you can use list comprehension as below

```
>>> [k for d in lst for k in d.keys()]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Or `[next(iter(i)) for i in L]`. Please can you rename your list, in many fonts `l` looks the same as `I`. In addition, you don't need to use `d.keys()`. `d` should suffice when iterating or using `list(d)`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to simply iterate over the list of dictionaries, and to iterate over the keys of each dictionary, using list comprehension as follows:

```
myList = [{0: 26}, {0: 36}, {1: 1}, {0: 215}, {1: 63}, {0: 215}]
newList = [k for d in myList for k in d]
print(newList) # [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are the keys so you would use the `dict.keys()` method:

```
L = [{0: 26},
     {0: 36},
     {1: 1},
     {0: 215},
     {1: 63},
     {0: 215}]

L2 = [list(d.keys())[0] for d in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

use keys() function of dict().

```
a = [{0: 26}, {0: 36}, {1: 1}, {0: 215}, {1: 63}, {0: 215}]
keys = list(a.keys()[0])
vaues = (a.values()[0])
```

Cheers!

Comment: Good luck applying `.keys()` and `.values()` on a list.

Comment: I did not notice that properly. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way :

```
list = [list(d.keys())[0] for d in originalList] #  originalList is the first list you posted
```

Here's the output : [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.keys` and `itertools.chain` to build a list of all keys:

```
from itertools import chain

w = [{0: 26},
   {0: 36},
   {1: 1},
   {0: 215},
   {1: 63},
   {0: 215}]

keys = list(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.keys, w)))
```

Answer (score 1):

OR try the below code, using `map`:

```
lod=[{0: 26},
 {0: 36},
 {1: 1},
 {0: 215},
 {1: 63},
 {0: 215}]
print(list(map(lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])))
```